# MICR / Check printing

Tags: windows-7, printing, quickbooks, quicken

I want to print my own checks on blank stock from Quicken and QuickBooks. To do so, I need a virtual driver that intercepts the print output from Quicken formats the fields properly, and adds the MICR text at the bottom of the check. This is for Windows 7 or OS X.

I have looked at the following:

[CHAX](http://www.chax.com/multichax.htm) Works, but crashes a LOT. Not giving me confidence. It is also expensive.

[VersaCheck](http://www.g7ps.com) Looks promising but looks like it suffers severe feature bloat. I just want to print check and deposit slips, thank you.

[Ganson](http://www.ganson.com/check_printing_software_selector.htm) Is only for high volume really. It is also designed for batch use vs I just want to print to a virtual printer. More than $2500.

[GnuMICR](http://sandeen.net/GnuMICR/) is more of a science project. Not yet ready to use and has not been updated for years.

There are a lot of solutions on the web, so please don't just google for me. I am looking for specific experience with good solid check printing solution.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Note that MICR data should be printed using magnetic ink or toner, so it's more complicated than just finding the right software package.

Comment: The mechanical printing part I have covered with an HP Printer and MICR cartridge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers, so I will answer my own question.

After searching the Web and downloading several examples, I found [Checksoft Premier](http://www.avanquest.com/USA/software/checksoft-premier-122159?meta=small-business&cat=software-for-small-business&sub=check-writing-software). I can print directly from Quicken onto blank check stock for several different account. There are some quirks in the program, but it seems to be working fine.

The other contender, [VersaCheck](http://www.g7ps.com/), is probably better software, but came with a severe license restriction: You must buy their check paper and enter a license code for each pack of checks you buy. The VersaChecks paper stock is about $0.03 / check premium to regular blank check stock. Unacceptable.